# how do I get raster columns at same level/height || Indent text within raster

Tags: tcolorbox, two-column, raster

```
\documentclass[12pt ]{res} % default is 10 pt
        
        \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}  %% use this to embed links  and remove blue box around link
    %%  \usepackage{academicons} %% use this for google scholar 
        \usepackage{xcolor}
        \usepackage[left=0.2in, right=0.8in, bottom=0.5in,top=0.2in, footskip=5pt]{geometry}
        \usepackage{microtype}
        \usepackage{enumitem} %% enum list item
        \usepackage{fancyhdr} %% fancy headers
        \usepackage{index} %% auto generated indexes
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{xfp}
    \usepackage{adjustbox}
    \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{blindtext}
         \usepackage{fontawesome}
        \setlength{\headsep}{0.2in}  % space between header and text
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % suppress line drawn by default by fancyhdr
    \pagestyle{fancy} % set pagestyle for the document
        \fancyhead{} 
        \fancyfoot{} % Set the right side of the footer to be the page number
\fancyhf{}


\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2, raster column skip=0.1cm, raster equal height]
    \begin{tcolorbox}[halign=left]
\section{Education} 

Samsung Institute of Technology
Some Institute of Technology         
\section{Core Skills} 
\section{Technical Skills} 
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[halign=left, opacityfill=0]
\section{Experience}  
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcbraster}
\end{resume}

\end{document}
```

On the right column the experience section is at the core skills (of left column). How do I make experience at the same level as education? Eventually the text will be added sections are needed?

Second, how do I make the left column stick to the left margin?

[image: added image of poor output]

Comment: any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Try this code. The `tcbraster` will work outside the environment `resume`. Although you can use this environment to produce the CV header: name, address, etc.

The gray box can be extended to the bottom of the page using the `raster height=` key. Its value must be adjusted taking into account the final height of the CV header.

[image: x]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{res} % default is 10 pt

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[left=0.2in, right=1in, bottom=0.5in,top=0.2in, footskip=5pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} %% fancy headers

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<
%
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.2in}  % space between header and text
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % suppress line drawn by default by fancyhdr
\pagestyle{fancy} % set pagestyle for the document
\fancyhead{} 
\fancyfoot{} % Set the right side of the footer to be the page number
\fancyhf{}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}  %must be the LAST package to be loaded ! <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

% ************************************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<
\makeatletter
\@fileswtrue
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\noindent{\sectionfont#1}}
\makeatletter
\def\opening{\def\@opening{}%
    \begingroup
    \print@name%
    \endgroup}
\makeatother
% ************************************************** 

\begin{document}
    
    \name{\bfseries first last\\[12pt]} % 
    
    \address{ address \\more address \\  city, state pinconde }
    \address{ \\XXX@gmail.com  \\ +91-70000-00000  \href{https://github.com/}{ \faGithub} \href{https://www.linkedin.com/in//}{ \faLinkedin} }  
    
    \begin{resume}
        \noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\linewidth}{1.2pt}}% changed <<<<<<<<<<<<
    \end{resume}    
    
    % This must be outside of resume
    \begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2, raster equal height=rows, raster height=2.2\linewidth] 
        \begin{tcolorbox}[halign=left]
            \parindent15pt
            \section{Education} 
            
            Samsung Institute of Technology
            
            Some Institute of Technology   
            
            \medskip\section{Core Skills} 
            
            \medskip\section{Technical Skills} 
        \end{tcolorbox}
        \begin{tcolorbox}[halign=left,  opacityfill=0]
            \section{Experience}  
        \end{tcolorbox}\\
    \end{tcbraster}
    
\end{document}
```

You may need to compile the document twice to get the right alignment.

`raster equal height=rows` writes the height of each box in the `tcbraster` to the `.aux` file and uses it when the `.aux` file is reread.

Comment: Sorry, when I compile your code using LateX the output is same, where experience is two line below in the right column, that is as earlier. I can't add image of the output in comments. I'm on OSX catalina 10.15.7, texshop 4.27 (4.27).

Comment: @Death Metal Please see the updated answer.